# ExtJS 6.0.2 - RowExpander collapses when store gets updated

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I'm trying to expand a row in a grid which has 20+ cells. The expander expands and collapses properly when it has no data within. But whenever I enter any value/data inside the expander, the store gets updated and expander collapses. the collapsed expander will not expand again if I click on the grid row.

```
Ext.define('RowExpanderWithComponents', {
extend : 'Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander',
alias: 'plugin.rowexpanderwithcomponents',

rowBodyTpl : new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div id="display-row-{id}"> </div>'
),

rowBodyCompTemplate: null,
expandOnClick: true,
hideExpandColumn: true,
enableTextSelection: true,
init : function(grid){
    var me = this,
        view;

    me.callParent(arguments);
    view = me.view = grid.getView();
    grid.addCls('rowexpanderwithcomponents');
    if(me.hideExpandColumn){
        grid.headerCt.query('gridcolumn')[0].hidden = true;
    }            
    if(me.enableTextSelection){
        view.enableTextSelection = true;
    }
    view.on('expandbody', function(rowNode, record, expandRow, eOpts){
        var recId = record.getId();
        if(!recId){
            Ext.Error.raise('grid-column-error');
        }
        var cont = this.getRowComponent(recId);
        if(cont){
            return;
        }

        var row = 'display-row-' + recId;
        clonedRowTemplate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(me.rowBodyCompTemplate));
        var parentCont = Ext.create(Ext.container.Container,{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            itemId: grid.getId() + '-parentRowExpCont-' + recId,
            items:[
                   me.replaceObjValues(clonedRowTemplate, record)
            ]
        });
        parentCont.render(row);
        var rowEl = parentCont.getEl().parent('.x-grid-rowbody');
        rowEl.swallowEvent(['mouseenter', 'click', 'mouseover', 'mousedown', 'dblclick', 'cellclick', 'itemmouseenter', 'itemmouseleave', 'onRowFocus', 'mouseleave']);
    });
    view.getRowComponent = me.getRowComponent;
    grid.getRowComponent = me.getRowComponent;
    grid.addToRowComponent = me.addToRowComponent;
    grid.addToRowComponent = me.addToRowComponent;
},
getRowComponent: function(recId){
    return Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#' + this.up('grid').getId() + '-parentRowExpCont-' + recId)[0];
},
removeAllFromRowComponent: function(recId){
    var rowCont = this.getRowComponent(recId);
    rowCont.removeAll();
},
addToRowComponent: function(recId, items){
    var rowCont = this.getRowComponent(recId);
    rowCont.add(items);
},
bindView: function(view) {
    if (this.expandOnClick) {
        view.on('itemclick', this.onItemClick, this);
    }
    this.callParent(arguments);
},
onItemClick: function(view, record, row, rowIdx, e,colIdx) {
        this.toggleRow(rowIdx, record);
},
rowExpanded: function(expander, record, body, rowIndex) { 
    var key = this.getRecordKey(record); 
    var status = { 
        rendered: true, expanded: true 
    }; this.recordStatus[key] = status; 
},
rowCollapsed: function(expander, record, body, rowIndex) { 
    var key = this.getRecordKey(record); 
    var status = { rendered: true, expanded: false }; 
    this.recordStatus[key] = status; 
},
onBeforeRefresh: function(view) { 
    var store = this.grid.getStore(), n, record; this.storedHtml = {}; 
    for (n = 0; n < store.data.items.length; n++) { 
        record = store.getAt(n); this.saveRowHtml(view, n, record); 
    } 
},
saveRowHtml: function(view, index, record) { 
    var key = this.getRecordKey(record); 
    var rowIndex = null, 
    found = false; 
    for (rowIndex in this.recordKeyAtRow) { 
        if (this.recordKeyAtRow[rowIndex] == key) { 
            found = true
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    if (found) { 
        var row = view.getRow(rowIndex); 
        var body = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('div.x-grid3-row-body', row); 
        this.storedHtml[key] = body.innerHTML; 
    } 
},
onRefresh: function(view) { 
    var store = this.grid.getStore(), n, row, record; 
    for (n = 0; n < store.data.items.length; n++) { 
        row = view.getRow(n); 
        if (row) { 
            record = store.getAt(n); 
            this.restoreRowHtml(view, n, record); 
        } 
    } 
}, 
restoreRowHtml: function(view, index, record) { 
    var key = this.getRecordKey(record); 
    var storedBody = this.storedHtml[key]; 
    if (!Ext.isEmpty(storedBody)) { 
        var row = view.getRow(index); 
        var body = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('div.x-grid3-row-body', row); 
        while (body.hasChildNodes()) { 
            body.removeChild(body.lastChild); 
        } 
        var status = this.recordStatus[key]; 
        if (!status) { 
            //the row has not been touched. 
            body.innerHTML = this.tpl.html; this.collapseRow(row); 
        } else { 
            body.innerHTML = storedBody; 
            if (status.expanded) this.expandRow(row); 
            else this.collapseRow(row); 
        } 
    } 
    this.markRow(view, index, record); 
},
markRow: function(view, index, record) { 
    var key; var row = view.getRow(index); 
    if (row) { 
        key = this.getRecordKey(record); 
        this.recordKeyAtRow[index] = key; 
    } 
}, 
markRows: function() { 
    var view = this.grid.getView(), 
    store = this.grid.getStore(), record, n; 
    this.recordKeyAtRow = {}; 
    for (n = 0; n < store.data.items.length; n++) { 
        record = store.getAt(n); 
        this.markRow(view, n, record); 
    } 
},
replaceObjValues: function( obj, record ){
    for( var all in obj )
    {
        if( typeof obj[all] === "string" && obj[all].match(/{{(.*)}}/) ){
            obj[all] = record.get(obj[all].match(/{{(.*)}}/)[1]);
        }
        if( typeof obj[all] === "object" && obj[all]!== null ){
            this.replaceObjValues( obj[all], record );
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

plugin for rowexpander.

*myform is the form which has textfields, buttons, comboboxes etc..

```
{
ptype: 'rowexpanderwithcomponents',
pluginId: 'Expander',
rowBodyCompTemplate: {
    xtype: 'container',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'myform',
        border: false     
    }],
 },
 }
```

Comment: can you please create working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) ? so I can try to resolve error

Comment: I have some problem with login in sencha. they didn't sent any confirmation emails about my membership.

Comment: Can you please check this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cl2)** ? I hope this will help you.

Comment: Please check this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2co0)

Comment: Please put data inside of store it will work

Comment: I didn't get you Narendra. Can you please make changes to code in that fiddle